# How to use convert every element from a nested list to a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, nested-lists

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'ID':['12345','23456','34567'],
         'Info':[[['Rob Kardashian', '00052369', '1987-03-17', 'Reality Star'], ['Brooke Barry', '00213658', '2001-03-30', 'TikTok Star']],
                [['Bae De Leon', '00896351', '1997-08-02', 'Volleyball Player'],['Jonas Blue', '02369785', '1990-08-02', 'Music Producer'],['Albert Einstein', '65231478', '1879-03-14','Scientist']],
                [['Robert Downey Jr', '23897410', '1965-04-04', 'Actor'],['Stan Lee','35239856','1922-12-28','Publisher & Producer']]]})
```

[image]

Hi folks, I have above dataframe and want to convert the elements in column 'Info' to rows.
I tried

```
[[pd.DataFrame(i) for i in k] for k in my_df ['Info'].tolist()]
```

But the outputs are not what I expected.

Expected outputs:
[image]

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why not have the ID repeated for the nested lists?

Comment: Yes. It also works for me. But just not sure how to create the table above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use grouping:

```
my_df.groupby("ID").Info.apply(lambda g: pd.DataFrame(g.iloc[0]))
```

This aggregates the returned dataframes for you:

```
>>> my_df.groupby("ID").Info.apply(lambda g: pd.DataFrame(g.iloc[0]))
                        0         1           2                     3
ID
12345 0    Rob Kardashian  00052369  1987-03-17          Reality Star
      1      Brooke Barry  00213658  2001-03-30           TikTok Star
23456 0       Bae De Leon  00896351  1997-08-02     Volleyball Player
      1        Jonas Blue  02369785  1990-08-02        Music Producer
      2   Albert Einstein  65231478  1879-03-14             Scientist
34567 0  Robert Downey Jr  23897410  1965-04-04                 Actor
      1          Stan Lee  35239856  1922-12-28  Publisher & Producer
```

You can then choose to reset the index and drop the `level_1` column:

```
expanded = my_df.groupby("ID").Info.apply(lambda g: pd.DataFrame(g.iloc[0]))
expanded.reset_index().drop("level_1", axis=1)
```

which gives you

```
      ID                 0         1           2                     3
0  12345    Rob Kardashian  00052369  1987-03-17          Reality Star
1  12345      Brooke Barry  00213658  2001-03-30           TikTok Star
2  23456       Bae De Leon  00896351  1997-08-02     Volleyball Player
3  23456        Jonas Blue  02369785  1990-08-02        Music Producer
4  23456   Albert Einstein  65231478  1879-03-14             Scientist
5  34567  Robert Downey Jr  23897410  1965-04-04                 Actor
6  34567          Stan Lee  35239856  1922-12-28  Publisher & Producer
```

Because this uses `GroupBy.apply()`, I don't expect this to be all that fast, however.

Having encapsulated Andy's and my versions in functions to run time trials indeed shows using my version would be the slower option:

```
In [99]: def np_concat(df):
    ...:     df = df.set_index('ID')
    ...:     pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(my_df.Info), index=my_df.index.repeat(my_df.Info.str.len()))
    ...:

In [100]: def groupby(df):
     ...:    df = df.groupby("ID").Info.apply(lambda g: pd.DataFrame(g.iloc[0]))
     ...:    df.reset_index().drop("level_1", axis=1)
     ...:

In [101]: %timeit np_concat(my_df)
1.08 ms ± 107 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

In [102]: %timeit groupby(my_df)
6.33 ms ± 394 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Thank you for walking through the answers!

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want:

```
my_df = my_df.set_index('ID')
pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(my_df.Info), \
             index=my_df.index.repeat(my_df.Info.str.len()))

Out[1102]:
                      0         1           2                     3
ID
12345    Rob Kardashian  00052369  1987-03-17          Reality Star
12345      Brooke Barry  00213658  2001-03-30           TikTok Star
23456       Bae De Leon  00896351  1997-08-02     Volleyball Player
23456        Jonas Blue  02369785  1990-08-02        Music Producer
23456   Albert Einstein  65231478  1879-03-14             Scientist
34567  Robert Downey Jr  23897410  1965-04-04                 Actor
34567          Stan Lee  35239856  1922-12-28  Publisher & Producer
```

---

**Note**: I leave `ID` as the index of the output `df`. If you need it as a column, chain additional `.reset_index` as follows:

```
pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(my_df.Info), \
            index=my_df.index.repeat(my_df.Info.str.len())).reset_index()

Out[1106]:
      ID                 0         1           2                     3
0  12345    Rob Kardashian  00052369  1987-03-17          Reality Star
1  12345      Brooke Barry  00213658  2001-03-30           TikTok Star
2  23456       Bae De Leon  00896351  1997-08-02     Volleyball Player
3  23456        Jonas Blue  02369785  1990-08-02        Music Producer
4  23456   Albert Einstein  65231478  1879-03-14             Scientist
5  34567  Robert Downey Jr  23897410  1965-04-04                 Actor
6  34567          Stan Lee  35239856  1922-12-28  Publisher & Producer
```

Comment: Yes. This solution perfectly solved my problem! Thanks!